# Is exim has ability to send notification with http postback?

Tags: postback, exim, exim4

I'm working on a service that gathers statistics for sending mail. Is there a way when Exim does notify external service that he successfully (or failed) send mail and target smtp service confirmed receiving the message using http postback?

Or may be here is exists other workarounds to get such kinds of notifications?

Answer (score 1):

You can `tail -F /path/main.log | parser | notifier` if you want.

`parser` and `notifier` are tools of your choice.